# DATE тип - как аргумент хранимой процедуры

Tags: sql, mysql

Ситуация такая, есть таблица:

[image: скрин]

### я пишу простейший селект

```
SELECT lessons.room 
FROM lessons 
WHERE lessons.lesson_date = '2014-04-19 23:39:24';
```

---

всё работает, я вижу свой БК-9

### Затем я "кладу" это в процедуру

```
DELIMITER |
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_my_date |

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_my_date (IN param DATE) 
BEGIN
    SELECT lessons.room 
    FROM lessons 
    WHERE lessons.lesson_date = param;
END;
|
DELIMITER ;
```

---

### Осталось эту процедуру вызвать

пишу

```
CALL sp_my_date('2014-04-19 23:39:24');
```

или

```
CALL sp_my_date('2014-04-19');
```

А результата нет (**Query OK, 0 rows affected**)

Подскажите почему не работает, вроде всё должно быть ок и row как минимум 1)

Answer (score 1):

Может, параметр функции сделать *строкой*? Или, передавая, в функцию использовать [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)?

Comment: Спасибо за отклик!!!
Всё оказалось проще: я из DATETIME - DATE вытаскиваю)))